# Вычисление непрозрачности child's, когда родитель имеет определенную непрозрачность

Tags: css, css3, html5

У меня есть родительский элемент, непрозрачность которого равна `0,5`. Я хочу, чтобы непрозрачность ребенка составляла `0,3`.

Каково должно быть исходное значение непрозрачности для родительского элемента?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53450703/7394871

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу `@Praveen Kumar Purushothaman` Я бы использовал переменные `CSS`, чтобы лучше контролировать это.

```css
.parent {
  opacity: var(--op, 0.5);
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: calc(var(--oc)/var(--op, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="--oc:0.3">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:50px;background:rgba(0,0,255,0.3)"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="--oc:0.4">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:50px;background:rgba(0,0,255,0.4)"></div>
```

Вы можете заметить, что у вас может быть только значение непрозрачности между `0` и `op`, что является логическим, так как ребенок не может быть более непрозрачным, чем родительский элемент, и потому что формула не позволит большего значения (у вас будет непрозрачность> 1, которая недействительна)

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452630/7394871): @Temani Afif

Comment: Alexandr_TT, ссылка ведет никуда...  `Ответ: @Temani Afif`

Comment: @Air Благодарю Исправил ссылку :)

Answer (score 2):

У вас должно быть `0.6` `Opacity` на то, что уже имеет `0.5` `Opacity`, чтобы окончательная непрозрачность была `0,3`.

Простая математика:

```
 0.5 × x = 0.3 (Значение, которое вам требуется)
    0.5   1
    --- = -
    0.3   x
    0.3 / 0.5 = 0.6 = x
```

```css
.parent, .child {padding: 5px;}
.parent {background: #f00; opacity: 0.5;}
.child {background: #f00; opacity: 0.6;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53450857/7394871): @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman